# Using RemoveEmptryEntries with .Split in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I have a string that's using semicolons as the delimitor.  I drop them into a List of strings,  and I want it to ignore Empty entries, but the option is throwing an error when I include it.  The working code looks like so:

```
    tContent = (HtmlInputText)FindControl("SomeInput");
    string tText = tContent.Value;
    List<string> tTextList = tText.Split(';').ToList();
```

To get rid of extra blank entries, I tried to employ this:

```
    tContent = (HtmlInputText)FindControl("SomeInput");
    string tText = tContent.Value;
    List<string> tTextList = tText.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

But it comes back with an error that it contains invalid arguments.  My best efforts seem to indicate that this should be valid, but the compiler disagrees.  I suspect a very silly error and I'm just in need of a second set of eyes in this case.

Comment: overloads of split are EITHER char OR char[] with remove entries.  You simply gave it the wrong options.  its annoying and it bites me each time i write a split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
List<string> tTextList = tText.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

to

```
List<string> tTextList = tText.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

You can see the supported signatures for `string.Split` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mkautzm SharpExtensions has an Extension Method for split to wrap around String.Split to make it easier. Its available as a nuget. COA, I'm the maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a char array:

```
List<string> tTextList = tText.Split(new char[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```